# Add input from list + numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say you have a code like this...

```
answer = input ()
areacode = ['302', '856', '215', '413']
if answer in areacode:
***Looking for what I would put here***
```

is it **possible** to have the users input from a list be added to numbers that would count up from 0000000 to 9999999?

Basically I want to ask the user to enter a area code and when they put the area code in, generate every possible outcome of a phone number up to the last number. EX: input is 302 so 302 + 0000000, then 302 + 0000001 all the way up to 3029999999 (I know this will take a long time)

I am using the newest version of Python.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in range(10000000):
    print(str(answer)+"{0:0=7d}".format(i))
```

Comment: You should increase the range argument by 1 to include the 9999999. E.g. `range(9)` counts only from 0 to 8 and `range(10)` is required to count up to 9.

Answer (score 3):

Python supports arbitrarily long integers. Just iterate over all these numbers, and add them to the area code multiplied by 10,000,000:

```
for i in range(10000000):
    print(answercode * 10000000 + i);
```

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments, redoing the multiplication in every iteration of the loop is wasteful, and be done only once, as the result does not change between iterations:

```
prefix = answercode * 10000000
for i in range(10000000):
    print(prefix + i);
```

Comment: won't multiplying take more time than string concatenation?

Comment: @Kylar technically speaking, multiplication is a machine-level instruction that takes O(1) time, if the numbers fit in registers. String concatenation takes O(n) time, where n is the length.

Comment: O(1) or not, repeating the same multiplication 10000000 times in a loop is wasting of CPU cycles, isn't it?

Comment: @VPfB good point - this can be done only once, outside the loop. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
for i in range(9999999):
        print("answer"+" "+"+"+(str(i).rjust(7, '0')))
```